# Tomcat can't start on CentsOS

Tags: centos, tomcat, java

Tomcat 6 installed via yum. When i try to start it, catalina.out contain:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

A have downloaded tomcat in .zip and run it - all ok, but I need to use tomcat installation from repo
And also when run java

Comment: what does the error message suggests?

Comment: How much memory does your system have?

Comment: -/+ buffers/cache:       1160       6699   total mamory 7859   Mem:          7859       7711        148          0         49       6501

Answer (score 0):

It seams Heap Size is more than your system RAM .

```
  Run the JVM with -XX:MaxHeapSize=256m (or any big number), and possibly -Xmx512m
```

Comment: it can run from root only. Any another user get error